# Missing key word argument in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword-argument

**CODE:**

```
def somef(*iterable_objs, positions):
    try:
        # some statement
    except TypeError:
        print('Argument \'positions\' is missing')
        return False
>>>somef([1,2,3], 'abc', (4,5,6))
```

`TypeError` is raised because argument `positions` is missing.
I would like to know if there is a method how to handle this exception

Comment: What were you actually trying to do there? How did you *want* Python to interpret this code? It's hard to help you accomplish your goal if you only show us a failed attempt to achieve it, and you don't tell us what you were actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Did you want `iterable_objs` to capture all but the last positional argument and `positions` to capture the last? Did you want `positions` to be keyword-only, but have the try-except handle what happens when `positions` isn't provided? Were you trying to do something else?

Comment: Yes i wanted to set all given arguments into one list ( `iterable_objs` ) and last one is `positions` ONLY if key word is included

Comment: It sounds like your function *should* just let the TypeError propagate if `positions` isn't provided. Catching exceptions is a bad thing if there's nothing you can reasonably do about them, as seems to be the case here.

Answer (score 6):

You can't use `*args` with other positional arguments following; `positions` is regarded as a *keyword-only argument* instead. Because it has no default value, it is still required.

Either give `positions` a default value to remove the requirement that it is always specified when calling:

```
def somef(*iterable_objs, positions=None):
    if positions is None:
        # calculate a default instead
        positions = range(len(iterable_objs))
```

or pass in a `positions` keyword argument explicitly:

```
somef([1,2,3], 'abc', positions=(4,5,6))
```

Side-note: never use `print()` to signal an error condition. The end user doesn't want to know that the programmer made a mistake, the *program* needs to hear about the error. Use `raise SomeException()` instead.

Comment: Of course, if you're just going to raise a `TypeError` when `positions` isn't provided, you might as well just not provide a default value and let Python raise that error for you. It's not clear what the questioner intended to do when `positions` isn't present, beyond perhaps a general sense that they wanted to "get rid of the errors".

Comment: @user2357112: yup, which is why I left it in; using `print()` to flag that an argument wasn't provided is definitely not the way to go either.

Comment: @user2357112: changed heart and replaced it with a sample default that is based on the other arguments.

Comment: Well, i want to iterate through `iterable_objs` and align items based on `positions` etc.. Whole code works as i want, but i want to handle all 'possible' situations that might happen when. Thanks for advice about that Error raising!

Answer (score 1):

As guys already mentioned if you use `positions` argument after `*iterable_objs` it is treated as *keyword-only argument* but if you change the order of arguments everything will work fine.

```
def somef(positions, *iterable_objs):
```

Comment: In this case i would follow @MartijnPieters answer and pass ``positions`` argument with explicit  *keyword*

Comment: Why does `positions` have to be last? It's your code, you can put arguments in any order for functions you create.

Answer (score 0):

If you won't always require a value to be passed for it, just supply a default:

```
def somef(*iterable_objs, positions=None):
```